# Load keras model with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, keras

I have a saved keras model for face recognition, based on the vgg-face architecture.
All that i want to know if there is a way to load it with java, more precisely in a spring boot application ?

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use Deep Java Library (DJL) to load Keras model in Java and run inference. DJL is an open source Deep Learning Library for Java. Checkout the github repo: https://github.com/awslabs/djl

There is a blogpost: https://towardsdatascience.com/detecting-pneumonia-from-chest-x-ray-images-e02bcf705dd6

And there is a blogpost specific use Keras model in springboot: https://medium.com/@kaviddiss/deep-learning-with-spring-boot-and-djl-757373e22abb

And the demo project can be found: https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo/blob/master/pneumonia-detection/README.md

And here is another demo using spring boot: https://github.com/aws-samples/djl-demo#model-serving-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk